# Could not find or load main class using makefile

Tags: java, class, makefile

I searched the suggested answers, but i failed to find working answer for me.
Makefile compiles everything with any error, but while trying to execute my java program I get error `Could not find main class bin.Program.class` Even if trying to compile program alone the same error pops out. 
I have multiple `.java` files, which has different classes in them and i'm using one library(.jar) file in directory `lib/`. Without it java compilator gives multiple errors.

```
SRC = src
LIBDIR = lib
BIN = bin
JAVA_FILES=${wildcard ${SRC}/*.java}
CLASS_FILES=${JAVA_FILES:${SRC}/%.java=${BIN}/%.class}
CLASSPATH="${LIBDIR}/*"
all: run
run: ${CLASS_FILES}
     java ${CLASS_FILES} -cp ${CLASSPATH}
${CLASS_FILES}: ${JAVA_FILES}
     javac $^ -d ${BIN} -cp ${CLASSPATH}
```

Eclipse compiles and runs program fine, and Program.java has main class.

Comment: What command are you using to invoke your application? Also, have you considered Ant instead of make?

Comment: I tried using `java bin.Program.class -cp bin` and `java bin.Program.class -cp lib` both givin same error as mentioned.
My assignment is to do a make file like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be inside of the bin directory and use

```
java -cp ./ Program
```

the bin is just a folder, so don't put that in.  And Program.class is not the name of the class, Program is.

Comment: while in bin folder this works `java -cp ./:../lib/* Program`. What can i do that this would work in my Makefile?

Comment: Sorry I don't know makefiles. So you are on your own there, maybe you can ask a separate question about that :)

Comment: Your Makefile has little to do with how you invoke your program. @Jay Smith's answer is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

With the answer given, it really helped, and makefile now looks like and it works:

```
SRC = src
LIBDIR = lib
BIN = bin
JAVA_FILES=${wildcard ${SRC}/*.java}
CLASS_FILES=${JAVA_FILES:${SRC}/%.java=${BIN}/%.class}
CLASSPATH="${LIBDIR}/*"
all: run
run: ${CLASS_FILES}
     java -cp ${BIN}:${LIBDIR}/* Program
${CLASS_FILES}: ${JAVA_FILES}
     javac $^ -d ${BIN} -cp ${CLASSPATH}
```